# video element not filling div completely (React Player)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html5-video, react-player

Code available here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-saha-i2j64?file=/src/App.js

I am having an issue getting React Player to fill the entirety of it's parent div, as you can see in the image below there is a little red on top/bottom

[image: image of video with red outline on top]

Since I have each respective element filling its container with

```
.video-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I would expect it to completely fill its container. Anyone have an idea of what I am missing?

Thanks.